# Ограничить длину дробной части в строке с помощью Stream API

Tags: java, java-8

Мне необходимо ограничить количество символов в строке после `'.'` до 6.
К примеру, из `"0.123456789"` получить `"0.123456"`.

Можно ли решить данную задачу используя Stream API?

Императивное решение у меня получилось такое:

```
static String f(String s) {
    if (s.contains(".")) {
        String dec = s.substring(s.indexOf('.'), s.length());
        if (dec.length() < 7)
            return s;
        else {
            String i = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('.'));
            return i + dec.substring(0, 7);
        }
    }
    else {
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Строка одна? Если так, то поток (stream) чего предполагается?

Comment: @Regent прикрепил решение без stream-ов. Да строка одна, но как я понял "text".chars() возвращает IntStream

Comment: В вашем решении, кстати, должно быть `dec.substring(0, 7)`. По поводу решения со Stream-ами: я могу представить себе один такой вариант, но, во-первых, там всё же будут не только потоки, а во-вторых, он будет длиннее варианта без потоков. Вероятно, размещу его в качестве ответа - мало ли, вдруг никто ничего толковее не придумает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение с использованием `indexOf` и `substring` можно укоротить:

```
public static String f(String str)
{
    final int maxCount = 6;
    int index = str.indexOf('.') + maxCount + 1;
    if (index == maxCount || index >= str.length())
    {
        return str;
    }
    return str.substring(0, index);
}
```

`if` и 2 `return`-a можно записать ещё короче:

```
return (index == maxCount || index >= str.length()) ? str : str.substring(0, index);
```

но это уже "на любителя", так как выражение получается достаточно длинное.

---

Добавить Stream символов строки, получаемый с помощью метода `chars`, сюда можно, однако дабы это не получилось сверхсложно и сверхкостыльно, высчитывание индекса и возврат `str` если символов после `.` меньше `6` придётся оставить вне потока. В результате, по сути, просто код `str.substring(0, index)` превращается в несколько строк кода:

```
public static String f(String str)
{
    final int maxCount = 6;
    int index = str.indexOf('.') + maxCount + 1;
    if (index == maxCount || index >= str.length())
    {
        return str;
    }
    return str.chars()
            .limit(index)
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
            .toString();
}
```